# Formset validation changes Django 1.6

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.6

I had the following code working in Django 1.5:

```
if formset.is_valid():
    formset.save()
```

The forms inside the formset are performing a check inside clean() to make sure that certain required fields are entered (only known at runtime). This means that although a user might not enter any values the validation would still run and ask for data entry if required.

With Django 1.6 this behaviour does not apply anymore. If there was no change then the form's clean() method does not get called anymore when calling formset.is_valid().

I could not find anything in the changelogs that would explain this new behvaiour. Is there a flag on formset.is_valid() to force the validation even if no changes were made?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the validation was skipped since the formset changed the form's edit_permitted attribute.

The following change fixed the issue I had:

```
  # Was required to disable shortcut for validation when
  # no data was entered
  for form in formset:
      form.empty_permitted = False
```